# When I export my files into .obj the model is showing all of the CMT lines and circles

Tags: modeling, rendering, export, transforms, error

I'm new to blender and I used the carver tool to help create my model and for some reason every time I try to export the file as an .obj the model isn't coming out right. I open the .obj on the 3D viewer app.[image].

Here's the model in blender:
[image]

Comment: What "carver tool"? - Don't recognise that expression unless you mean sculpting! We'd also need to see what your object looks like in Blender.

Comment: Oh sorry! That was my mistake, I meant the carver add-on, its sort of an in-build add on that you can use to make cuts into models. I added an image of the model in blender.

Comment: Ah ok. To be honest I didn't know there was a buit-in addon called 'carver' and I've never ever heard anyone mention it before in all the time I've been using Blender! Unfortunately that image you've added doesn't really show any details of how your object has been constructed so I think we'd need to see the blend file to go any further which you can share here: https://blend-exchange.com/. Follow the instructions on that page.